# change a field and port mysql table data via script ?

Tags: mysql, bash, porting

```
mysql> desc oldtable;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| active        | char(1)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


mysql> desc newtable;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| active     | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I would like to port data (dump) from oldtable into newtable. One issue is, earlier the table used char(1) for active  which stores value either 'Y' or 'N'. Now the newtable stores it as int either 1 or 0.

How can i fix this before porting data? Should I use shell script for such fix & porting ? 
Any sample scripts or tips  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO newtable 
SELECT uid,IF(active='Y',1,0) as active FROM oldtable
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO newtable (uid, active)
    SELECT uid, IF(active='Y', 1, 0) AS active
    FROM oldtable
```

docs for this syntax here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html

Answer (score 0):

Joking version:

```
INSERT INTO newtable 
SELECT uid,FIELD(active,'Y') as active 
FROM oldtable
```