# how to port data to a table when both tables has different fields

Tags: mysql

```
 mysql> desc oldtable;
 +---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
 +---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | uid           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
 | active        | char(1)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 | field3        | char(256)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 | field4        | char(256)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 +---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


 mysql> desc newtable;
 +------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
 +------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | uid        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
 | active     | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
 | field5     | int(12)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
 | field6     | varchar(12)  | NO   |     | 0       |                |
 | field7     | varchar(12)  | NO   |     | 0       |                |
 +------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This is similar to my previous query [change a field and port mysql table data via script ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792443)
[I would like to port data (dump) from oldtable into newtable. One issue is, earlier the table used char(1) for active which stores value either 'Y' or 'N'. Now the newtable stores it as int either 1 or 0.

How can i fix this before porting data? Should I use shell script for such fix & porting ? Any sample scripts or tips :)]

But this question, How to achieve the same porting,If both tables has different no.of fields 
like above?

Comment: `field5, field7 and field7` are **not nulls** in newtable. How do you want to fill them up while porting the data from oldtable?

Comment: Why not use `ENUM('Y','N')` for `active`?  All the advantages of `TINYINT` whilst still presenting a string interface.  Otherwise, wouldn't you just use `IF(oldtable.active = 'Y', 1, 0)`?

Comment: @anubhava - Sorry,I should been more clearer, I want to port only the field uid and active . Where active has different data type.

Comment: @eggyal, I'm not whether we can change the field from TINYINT To ENUM,because this change will also affect few other scripts..so more changes ,which we would like to avoid.

Comment: Thanks for answering my query. I think @danihp has provided the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is similar to the previus question answer:

```
INSERT INTO newtable (uid, active, field5, field6, field7 )
SELECT uid,FIELD(active,'Y') as active, 0,'',''
FROM oldtable
```

Then update newTable with new fields values:

```
update newTable
set 
  field5 = (select someExpression from someTable5 t where t.uid=newTable.uid),
  field6 = (select someExpression from someTable6 t where ...),
  field7 = (select someExpression from someTable7 t where ...)
```

Also, you can define new fields as null allowed and leave this fields without value.